# AttributeError: module 'keras.engine.base_layer' has no attribute 'BaseRandomLayer'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Context - I was getting errors when saving/loading EfficientNetB7 and one of the articles I saw suggested installing tf-nightly. Well that really blew things up in my Google Colab! I uninstalled tf-nightly, restarted my runtime, and now when I go to run my import cell, I get the errors below.

I reinstalled tensorflow 2.6.0.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-5d853ee59f92> in <module>()
     11 import tensorflow as tf
     12 from tensorflow import keras
---> 13 from tensorflow.keras import Model
     14 from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
     15 from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

11 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/core/dropout.py in <module>()
     24 
     25 @keras_export('keras.layers.Dropout')
---> 26 class Dropout(base_layer.BaseRandomLayer):
     27   """Applies Dropout to the input.
     28 

AttributeError: module 'keras.engine.base_layer' has no attribute 'BaseRandomLayer'
```

I also had an issue with this import before:

```
from tensorflow.keras import backend as keras
```

Here are all my imports:

```
import os
import glob
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.transform import resize
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.losses import categorical_crossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, BatchNormalization

from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, LearningRateScheduler
from datetime import datetime

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score, f1_score, precision_score, recall_score

import skimage.io as io
import skimage.transform as trans
from tensorflow.keras import models
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras.models import *
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import *
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, LearningRateScheduler
from tensorflow.keras import backend as keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers.schedules import ExponentialDecay

import scipy.misc as sc
import h5py

from sklearn.semi_supervised import LabelSpreading
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

from tensorflow.keras.applications import * #Efficient Net included here
import shutil
from sklearn import model_selection
from tqdm import tqdm

# import warnings
# warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)
```

Comment: Open a new notebook in colab and paste the entire code in that notebook without installing/uninstalling tensorflow code. This will resolve above mentioned import error. Let us know the exact traceback error of saving/loading EfficientNetB7 model.

Answer (score 0):

Try rolling back the python version to 3.6. If you are using Anaconda run

`conda install python=3.6`

Then install keras

`pip install keras==2.0.8`

Worked for me in Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you explain why did this work?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get rid of the issue after installing tensorflow==2.8.0.

Answer (score 0):

Post  tensorflow-2.13.1 there is some issue , Mid term remedy would be to roll back `!pip install tensorflow==2.12.1`